# Trying to localize an outside package variable through a lexical binding in Perl

Tags: perl, variables, internals, lexical-scope

It's a long title, but I'm afraid I can't take a single word out without losing the true meaning of the question.  I'll give a quick description of what I'm trying to achieve first, then a long rambling on why I want it done this way. Skip the rambling if you intend to directly answer abiding with the question title :-)

### Quick description

Assuming the existence of a `lexicalize` builtin that does just what I want, here goes:

```
package Whatever;
{
  lexicalize $Other::Package::var;
  local $var = 42;
  Other::Package->do_stuff; # depends on that variable internally
}
```

### Whys and whynots

For a bit of context, I'm whitebox-testing a third-party module.

I want the variable **localized** because I want it changed for a limited time only, before the tests move on to something else.  `local` is the best way I found to do this without depending on knowing the module's choice for an initial value.

I want a **lexical binding** for two main reasons:

1. I don't want to pollute the test file's higher-level namespace.
2. I want something shorter than the fully-qualified name.  It's not in the sample code for brevity, but I use the identifier a lot more than what's shown, with calculations and updates relative to its previous value.

I couldn't decently use `our` because it won't grab a variable from another package: “No package name allowed for variable $Other::Package::var in "our".”  Cheating to temporarily enter Other::Package's scope doesn't cut it: if I use a block (`{ package Other::Package; our $var }`) then the binding doesn't last long enough to be useful; and if I don't (`package Other::Package; our @var; package main`) then I need to know and copy the previous package's name, which prevents moving that piece of code around too much.

While doing my homework before asking a previous form of this question, I discovered `Lexical::Var`, which seemed like it would be *exactly* what I needed.  Alas: “Can't localize through a reference.”

I've also tried my best on my gut feeling of `my *var`-based forms, but kept bumping into syntax errors.  I've learned more than I cared to about scoping and binding today :-)

I can't think of a reason why what I want shouldn't be possible, but I can't find the right incantation.  Am I asking for an unfortunate unimplemented edge case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not quite sure if I understand you correctly. Does this help?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

{
    package This;
    use warnings; use strict;
    our $var = 42;

    sub do_stuff {
        print "$var\n";
    }
}

{
    package That;
    use warnings; use strict;

    use Lexical::Alias;
    local $This::var;

    alias $This::var, my $var;

    $var = 24;
    print "$var\n";

    This->do_stuff;
}

package main;

use warnings; use strict;

This->do_stuff;
```

Comment: Lexical::Alias... hasn't found that one while looking around.  Seems promising.  Trying it out, I'll let you know shortly.

Comment: Interesting stuff.  You've just made me understand just a bit more of the internals than I wanted to.  As far as my formulation of the question goes, it's valid (so I'll upvote and accept).  Because I've been stupid and omitted a bit too much, it's not exactly what I wanted, but I'm only blaming myself now.

Comment: What I omitted: my `local` line is actually `local $pkg::var = f($pkg::var)`.  `local` has to be done before the aliasing or it breaks it, so I'm left writing the huge fully-qualified name three times, which is a bit over what I was targetting.

Answer (score 3):

If I get you right, all you need is our. Forgive me if I dont.

Here's working example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

package Some;

our $var = 42;
sub do_stuff { return $var }

package main;

{
    local $Some::var = 43;
    print "Localized: " . Some->do_stuff() . "\n";
};

print "Normal: " . Some->do_stuff() . "\n";
```

But if you try to localize private (`my`) variable of some package, you probably doing something wrong.

Comment: It works indeed: I'm currently already using a variation of this, for lack of something better.  Where this fails to meet my own requirements is that it doesn't create a new (shorter) lexical binding: inside the block, we're stuck to using the fully-qualified `$Some::var` form of the variable instead of a nicer plain `$var`.  My actual package name is quite a bit longer than that; this is what prompted my question in the first place.

Comment: Side note: this might be a side effect of your copy-pasting multiple files in a single code sample, but your `our $var = 42` line near the top will likely pollute anything you'd want to try in the target block later on.  Better wrap package `Some` in a block.

Answer (score 3):

there are several ways to do this:

- given:

  ```
  {package Test::Pkg;
      our $var = 'init';
      sub method {print "Test::Pkg::var = $var\n"}
  }
  ```
- alias a package variable from the current package to the target package.

  ```
  {
      package main;
      our $var;

      Test::Pkg->method; #     Test::Pkg::var = init

      local *var = \local $Test::Pkg::var;  
          # alias $var to a localized $Test::Pkg::var

      $var = 'new value';

      Test::Pkg->method; #    Test::Pkg::var = new value
  }

  Test::Pkg->method;     #    Test::Pkg::var = init
  ```
- localize through a glob reference:

  ```
  {
      package main;

      my $var = \*Test::Pkg::var;  # globref to target the local

      Test::Pkg->method; #     Test::Pkg::var = init

      local *$var = \'new value';  # fills the scalar slot of the glob

      Test::Pkg->method; #    Test::Pkg::var = new value
  }

  Test::Pkg->method;     #    Test::Pkg::var = init
  ```
- bind a the lexical in the target package, and let it spill into the current package:

  ```
  {
      package Test::Pkg;  # in the target package
      our $var;           # create the lexical name $var for $Test::Pkg::var

      package main;       # enter main package, lexical still in scope

      Test::Pkg->method; #     Test::Pkg::var = init

      local $var = 'new value';

      Test::Pkg->method; #    Test::Pkg::var = new value
  }

  Test::Pkg->method;     #    Test::Pkg::var = init
  ```

the last example uses a slightly awkward double package declaration to create a lexical in one package and get it into another.  This trick is useful with `local` in other scenarios:

```
 no strict 'refs';
 local ${'Some::Pkg::'.$name} = 'something';
 use strict 'refs';
```

Comment: Reading your answer after hobbs's (SO order), the same comment applies.  Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @JB. => added a few more examples that don't pollute the namespace.

Comment: Your second one, in addition to reminding me things I didn't want to remember on typeglobs (a leitmotiv in this question), seems like a sane basis for what I want to do.  Tweaking a bit...

Comment: YES!  Minor tweak on your second answer: `my $ref = \*Other::Package::var; local *$ref = \(my $var = f($$$ref));`  (I need the localized variable non-constant, accessible for easy modifying as `$var`, and initialized as a function of the original value)  This seems to fit all of my expressed and non-expressed (asking questions is *hard*) requirements.  Congratulations!  PS would you mind editing to bring that part of the answer to the top?  (first answer non-lexical leak; third answer requires knowledge of enclosing package name)  PPS glad to have found a mostly reasonable use for a `$$$form`.

Answer (score 2):

```
package Other::Package;

$var = 23;

sub say_var {
  my $label = shift;
  print "$label: $Other::Package::var\n";
}

package Whatever;
Other::Package::say_var("before");
{
  local $Other::Package::var = 42;
  local *var = \$Other::Package::var;
  Other::Package::say_var("during");
  print "\$Whatever::var is $var inside the block\n";
}
Other::Package::say_var("after");
print "\$Whatever::var is ",
    defined($var) ? "" : "un", "defined outside the block\n";
```

Output:

```
before: 23
during: 42
$Whatever::var is 42 inside the block
after: 23
$Whatever::var is undefined outside the block
```

`local $Other::Package::var` makes the original value temporarily 42 for the duration of the block, and `local *var = \$Other::Package::var` makes `$var` in the current package an alias for `$Other::Package::var` temporarily for the duration of the block.

Naturally some of this isn't `strict`-compliant, but I avoided using `our` because `our` obfuscates the issue if both packages are in the same file (as they might be if you copy-pasted this sample) — the `our` declaration can leak out of the package it's used in, into a following package in the same file :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  It's not precisely exactly what I was looking for since it leaks the aliasing to *Whatever::var outside of the lexical scope (I'm thinking helper functions in Whatever).  Thanks for taking the time to try and help me out, much appreciated.

Comment: @JB. ah, in that case Lexical::Alias is what you want (as Sinan said). I was trying to avoid that, since it's sort of a tricky beast.